# Como extrair conteúdo da Web (Web scraping) com C#?

Tags: c#, web-scraping

Recentemente aprendi a fazer web scraping e consegui em alguns sites, mas noutros não consigo. Reparei que em alguns dos que não consigo existe um "#", o que isso significa?

Vou dar um exemplo de um site em que isso me acontece.
https://www.meusresultados.com/jogo/IV9KYMDp/#h2h;overall

Também existe alguma maneira de fazer web scraping neste site?

Costumo fazer assim:

```
var wc = new WebClient();
wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
var pagina = wc.DownloadString(url);

var htmlDocument = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
htmlDocument.LoadHtml(pagina);
```

E depois acho o node que quero.

Comment: ter como tem... mas tem q ver o que você está fazendo...

Comment: Como assim tenho de ver o que estou fazendo?

Comment: isso...tinha q ver o código q vc está usando... e, não está funcionando porque esse código só vai receber o html do servidor em uma requisição... muitos sites trabalham com javascript e vão carregando os dados depois que a página está carregada... por isso quando você recebe o html não tem dados lá...

Comment: Então como posso proceder para obter esses dados?

Comment: é uma gambiarra... mas poderia usar um webBrowser, após o evento `DocumentComplete` você espera um tempo (pra carregar o javascript) e então você consegue acesso ao html do browser.... dei uma olhada rápida no site, não achei os endereços que a requisição ajax é feita... então... acho que só na gambiarra mesmo...

Comment: Já tinha tentado com webBrowser, mas não funcionou. Dever ser complicado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aqui vai um web scraper que pega todas as referências a outras URIs, de uma URI:

```
public class WebScraper
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string url = args[0];

        foreach (string anotherUrl in GetScrapedUrls(url))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(anotherUrl);
        }
    }

    private static bool IsValidChunk(string chunk)
    {
        bool result = true;

        result = result && chunk.First() != '#';
        result = result && !chunk.Contains("clicklogger");
        result = result && !chunk.StartsWith("https");
        result = result && !chunk.Contains("captcha");
        result = result && !chunk.Contains("counter");

        return result;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GetScrapedUrls(string url)
    {
        Uri myUri;
        if (Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.Absolute, out myUri))
        {
            yield return myUri.AbsoluteUri;

            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            string content = client.DownloadString(myUri);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(content) && content.IndexOf("<html>") > 0)
            {
                MatchCollection matches =
                    Regex.Matches(content, @"<a[^>]+?href\s*?=\s*?['""]([^'""]+)['""]");

                foreach (Match match in matches)
                {
                    string chunk = match.Groups[1].Value;

                    if (IsValidChunk(chunk))
                    {
                        string oneMoreUrl = 
                            (url.IndexOf("http") != 0 ? url : "") + 
                                (url.Last() == '/' ? "" : "/") + 
                                    chunk;

                        foreach (string evenOneMoreUrl in GetScrapedUrls(oneMoreUrl))
                        {
                            yield return evenOneMoreUrl;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```